# Python: Patch internal library function in part of the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, patch, monkeypatching

In Python I want to patch the `requests.request` to do some custom things (e.g. `print` something) so all functions imported through my module do it.

However, I want it so the original `requests` functions keep their old behaviour while not reimplementing all the functions again. Is that possible?

## Intro you can skip if you know the `requests` library

`requests` has a module `api` where the `request` function is implemented. Other convenience functions like `get`, `post` etc. call this function so it is easy to change their behaviour by changing the `request` function in the `api` module.

## Code

```py
# my_requests.py
from requests import api, get, head, post, patch, put, delete, options

def request(method, url, **kwargs):
    my_additional_string_for_fun = kwargs.pop("fun_string", "")
    print(f"requesting with method {method}\n{my_additional_string_for_fun}")
    with sessions.Session() as session:
        # some fiddling with the session object here
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

api.request = request
```

But trying it out:

```
>>> import my_requests
>>> my_requests.get("http://httpstat.us/200", fun_string="Hi there!")
requesting with method get
Hi there!
<Response [200]>
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("http://httpstat.us/200", fun_string="Hi there!")  # I want this to raise TypeError
equesting with method get
Hi there!
<Response [200]>
```

It seems I've changed it even when I import it through `requests`. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate: I know this can be solved by copy-pasting [this](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/api.py#L64) and the rest of the file to `my_requests.py` but I'm curious if it can be solved without doing it.